# Mersenne primes and the modulus operation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, mersenne-numbers

Let $p=2^q-1$ be a Mersenne prime. I then want to prove that
$$
x\equiv ((x \text{ mod } 2^q) + \lfloor x/2^q\rfloor) \quad(\text{mod } p)
$$
How do I do this?
Any sort of help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your writing is not clear as normally you don't use multiple $\text{mod}$ in one equation. Do you mean $x\equiv ((x \text{ mod } 2^q) + \lfloor x/2^q\rfloor )\quad(\text{mod } p)$?

Comment: What have you tried? Try resolving those $\equiv$ symbols: $x\equiv a \text{ mod }p$ is equivalent to: $\exists k\in \mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $x = k\cdot p + a$.

Comment: I have edited my post to make it more clear now @LegNaiB

Comment: In general $x\equiv (x\bmod n+1)+\lfloor \frac x{n+1} \rfloor\pmod n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not require Mersenne primes. It’s just simple in a computer because of binary arithmetic when $M=2^q.$

Given $M>0$ then:

$$x\bmod M=x-M\left\lfloor\frac xM\right\rfloor$$

So $$\begin{align}(x\bmod M) + \left\lfloor\frac xM\right\rfloor&=x-(M-1)\left\lfloor\frac xM\right\rfloor\\
&\equiv x\pmod {M-1}
\end{align}$$

Your case is $M=2^q.$ wWe don’t need $M-1$ prime.

---

When $M=10,$ this is the induction step in showing that the sum of the digits of a number is congruent to the number modulo $M-1=9,$ and you get a similar result in any base $M.$

Indeed, another way to write the above proof is to write $x$ in base $M.$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Then I can prove that $(x \text{ mod } 2^q) + \lfloor x/2^q \rfloor = x- p\lfloor x/2^q\rfloor$. But why does this imply that $x\equiv ((x \text{ mod } 2^q) + \lfloor x/2^q\rfloor) \quad(\text{mod } p)$?

Comment: For any integers $A,B,C,p$ if $A=B-pC$ then $A\equiv B\pmod p.$ Here $$A=(x\bmod 2^q)+\lfloor x/2^q\rfloor, B=x, C=\lfloor x/2^q\rfloor.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great answers. That helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the congruence modulo $2^q$: This means $\exists k\in\mathbb{Z}$, s.t.
$x = k\cdot 2^q + a$ for $0 \leq a \leq 2^q-1$.

Entering this into the formula yields
\begin{align}
k\cdot 2^q+a&\equiv \left(a + \left\lfloor \frac{k\cdot 2^q+a}{2^q}\right\rfloor\right) \mod p \\
k\cdot 2^q + a&\equiv a + k \mod p \\
2^q &\equiv 1 \mod p \\
2^q -1 & \equiv 0 \mod p
\end{align}

Where the last equation is certainly true and by reasoning from bottom to top you get the desired equivalence.

The step from the first to the second line does work as $ a< 2^q$, so that flooring removes this part and only $k$ is left after dividing with $2^q$.